# jQuery slideToggle() not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following table dynamically generated from a view. I need to add click event on `class=heading` to to show or hide `class=content`.

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="thead">Function</th>
        <th  class="thead"">Type</th>
        @foreach (var item in Model.PackageNames)
        {
            <th class="thead">
                @item
            </th>
        }
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.PrivilegeGroups)
    {
        <tr>
            <td colspan="50">
                <div class="heading">
                    @item.Name
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <text>
            <p class="content">
                @foreach (var privilege in item.Privileges.Values)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @privilege.Name
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @privilege.Type.ToString()
                        </td>
                        @foreach (var package in privilege.Packages)
                        {
                           <td>
                                @package.AccessLevel.ToString()
                           </td>
                        }
                    </tr>
                }
            </p>
        </text>
    }
</tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the jQuery I'm using, however it does not work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".heading").click(function () {
            $(this).next(".content").slideToggle(500);
        });
    });   // -- End Ready
</script>
```

However, `$('.content').slideToggle();` does work and toggles all elements with `class=content`. I want to hide only the next element. How do I make it work?

Thanks.

Comment: You have malformed and invalid HTML. In a `tbody` you can only have a `tr`, and inside that a `th` or `td`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much @Garrett Fogerlie and @saganbyte, i finally resolved it by moving `class=heading` from within `<td>`to `<tr>` and `$(this).next(".content").slideToggle(500);` works now!

```
@foreach (var item in Model.PrivilegeGroups ) {
        <tr class="heading">
            <td colspan="50">
                    @item.Name
            </td>
        </tr>
        <p class="content">
            @foreach (var privilege in item.Privileges.Values)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td class="thead">
                        @privilege.Name
---Rest of the code here
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, since inside a `<tbody>` only `<th>`, `<tr>` and `<td>` are allowed, I think your `<tbody>` should look something like this:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.PrivilegeGroups)
    {
        <tr>
            <td colspan="50" class="heading">
                @item.Name
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="content">          
            @foreach (var privilege in item.Privileges.Values)
            {
                <td>
                    @privilege.Name
                </td>
                <td>
                    @privilege.Type.ToString()
                </td>
                @foreach (var package in privilege.Packages)
                {
                    <td>
                        @package.AccessLevel.ToString()
                    </td>
                }
            }
         </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

I'm not very good with javascript, however I think you could try replacing `$(this).next(".content").slideToggle(500);` with `$(this).closest(".content").slideToggle(500);` or `$(this).next("p").slideToggle(500);`

If those don't work, you could try to use a unique `id` instead of a `class` like this:

```
<tbody>
    @{ int i = 0; }
    @foreach (var item in Model.PrivilegeGroups)
    {
        <tr>
            <td colspan="50" class="heading">
                @item.Name
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="content@i">          
            @foreach (var privilege in item.Privileges.Values)
            {
                <td>
                    @privilege.Name
                </td>
                <td>
                    @privilege.Type.ToString()
                </td>
                @foreach (var package in privilege.Packages)
                {
                    <td>
                        @package.AccessLevel.ToString()
                    </td>
                }
            }
         </tr>
    @{ i++ } 
    }
</tbody>
```

Then update your javascript accordingly.

Like I said, I'm not good with javascript/jquery, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your jquery code is run 'after' the data has loaded/rendered on the page?

Can you try 'live' instead of 'click'? So that would change your jquery code to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".heading").live('click', function () {
            $(this).next(".content").slideToggle(500);
        });
    });   // -- End Ready
</script>
```

One way to check is to run the jquery code in firebug (if in FF) once the page has loaded and see what works for you and then update the code in your script tags accordingly.

Comment: i tried this but still not working. On debugging script, i see error next is undefined!. I also tied $(this).closest(".content") as suggested by Garrett Fogerlie, still see the same error.

Comment: The way .closest() is being used needs jQuery 1.6+. Can you confirm that the version of jQuery you are using is 1.6 or higher? I d just update the jquery version I m using to the latest and then try whatever I m hoping to accomplish by running it from Firebug console(Firefox) after the data was loaded. In the console I d first check if I m able to get all the .heading tags, then I d apply a .live on it and test if its getting triggered and then I d attempt getting to the .content item in one way or the other. This exercise will tell me where the issue could be.